# Is the topology coherent if each $X_i$ is open in $\bigcup_j X_j$?

Tags: general-topology

I am studying topology and the following was stated in one of the lectures.

**Definition.** Given topological spaces $(X_i, \mathcal T_i)$'s, the topology
$$
\mathcal T := \{U\subseteq X : U\cap X_i\in\mathcal T_i\}
$$
on $X := \bigcup_i X_i$ is called *coherent* w.r.t. $(X_i, \mathcal T_i)$'s iff $\mathcal T_i = \mathcal T|_{X_i}$ for each $i$. ($\mathcal T|_{X_i}$ denotes the subspace topology on $X_i$ induced by $\mathcal T$.)

It was then stated that

> $\mathcal T$ is coherent in the following cases:
>
> 1. If $X_i$'s are disjoint.
> 2. If each $X_i$ is open in $X$.

I can easily check (1) (and in fact, in this case, each $X_i$ will be clopen in $X$). But I am having trouble proving (2).

Any ideas?

Comment: In fact I think it is false...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false: let $X_1 = \mathbb{N}$ with the discrete topology and $X_2 = \mathbb{N}$ with the antidiscrete topology. Then $\mathcal{T}$ is the antidiscrete topology on $\mathbb{N}$ and it induces the antidiscrete topology on $X_1$, which obviously does not coincide with the (discrete) topology of $X_1$.

Comment: Yes, I know that $\mathcal T|_{X_i}\subseteq \mathcal T_i$ will hold straight from the definition. But I can't seem to use the openness of $X_i$'s to prove the other inclusion.

Comment: @Atom Ok, I have to take back the hints. See my new answer.